# How to make two objects acting like parenting to each ohter?

Tags: constraints, parent

I understand parenting two objects
Circle A to B
Circle B to A
will result unwanted behavior.
But let's say I want when Circle A rotates, B will follow, and it should work the same when Circle B rotate, A should follow.

The rotation should be initiated from either A or B.

What would be the solution for this?

Comment: Cyclic parenting requires a memory-full system, which means that to calculate the position of the objects Blender needs to know the entire history of the state of the 2 objects. 
If you want to create a keyframed animation, you need to do a kind of simulation in python and bake it, or maybe you could find a simpler way by turning on/off some copy Rotation constraints. 
But if you want to be able to rotate both of them in the viewport like you rotate normal objects, I don't think it's possible.
Try explaining more what you want to do, we may find a workaround

Comment: Do you know how to turn on and off the rotation constraints by rotating the circle? For example turning circle A will disable the rotation constraint on A, but turn on the one on the B, and vice versa? 
But also retaining the transformation constraint value when the constraint is turned off. So the circle don't get back to the original position in view port.

Comment: Cheat and have two copies. Show/hide them with keyframes.

Comment: @JuanFeju as I said, you could also do that, but you'll need to do some scripting in python and you would need to bake it. To have automatic cyclic parenting it's the only way, so If you only have a small animation, like amonroejj said, the best way it trying to find a cheat, depending on your needs